# For $f(x,y,z,\ w)=x^{5}+xy^{2}-zw$, how is this stationary point $\;$ a saddle point? - Question 14

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

[14.](http://home.bi.no/a0710194/Teaching/BI-Mathematics/GRA-6035/2011/problems7.pdf) a$)$ Find all stationary points of $f(x,y,z,\ w)=x^{5}+xy^{2}-zw$.

$b)$ Classify the stationary points of $f$ as local maxima, local minima or saddle points.

[Provided Solution](http://home.bi.no/a0710194/Teaching/BI-Mathematics/GRA-6035/Exams/final-2014-05-sol.pdf) a $)$ We compute the partial derivatives $f_{x}'=5x^{4}+y^{2},\ f_{y}'=2xy,\ f_{z}'=-w$ and $f_{w}'=-z$. The stationary points are given by
$
5x^{4}+y^{2}=0,\ 2xy=0,\ -w=0,\ -z=0
$. This gives $z=w=0$ from the last two equations, and $x=y=0$ from the first two. The stationary points are therefore $(x,y,z,w)=(0,0,0,0)$ .

$b)$ We compute the second order partial derivatives of $f$ and form the Hessian matrix
$$
H(f)=\left(\begin{array}{llll}
20x^{3} & 2y & 0 & 0\\
2y & 2x & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$
We see that the second order principal minor obtained from the last two rows and columns is
$
\left|\begin{array}{l}
0-1\\
-10
\end{array}\right|=-1<0
$.
Hence the Hessian is indefinite. Hence the stationary point is a saddle point.

> I see that $H[ \, f( \, (x, y, z, w) = \mathbf{0} \, ) \, ] = \left(\begin{array}{llll}
> 0& 0 & 0 & 0\\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
> 0 & 0 & -1 & 0
> \end{array}\right)
> $. Cofactor-expand along the 3rd and 4th column. Then $\det( \, H[ \, f( \mathbf{0} \, ) \, ] \, ) = 0$. According to the criteria beneath, doesn't this mean the nature of $(x, y, z, w) = \mathbf{0}$ is unknown? How's it indefinite?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Near a critical point $p$,
$$f(p+h) = f(p)+0+\frac12 h^t H(p)h+R(p,h),$$
i.e.,
$$f(p+h)−f(p) = \frac12 h^t H(p)h+R(p,h)$$
(quadratic therm plus "garbage" of higher order).

When H(p) is definite positive/negative, the quadratic term is dominant near $p$. When H(p) is *semi* definite, the the quadratic term can be zero in some points and all depends of the "garbage".

In your case (polynomial!), there is no need of using Taylor. The quadratic term is −zw that is dominant except when zw=0, but takes positive and negative values and (0,0,0,0) is a saddle point.

When the Hessian gives no information about a critical point $p$, study the sign of $f-f(p)$ near $p$. In this case:
$$f(0,0,\epsilon,\epsilon)=-\epsilon^2<0$$
$$f(0,0,\epsilon,-\epsilon)=\epsilon^2>0$$
and $(0,0,0,0)$ is a saddle point.

Comment: I don't understnad your answer sorry. How does it answer my question?

Comment: Near a critical point $p$, $f(p+h) = f(p)+0+h^tH(p)h/2+R(p,h)$, i.e. $f(p+h)-f(p) = h^tH(p)h+R(p,h)$ (quadratic ther plus "garbage" of higher order). When $H(p)$ is definite positive/negative, the quadratic term is dominant. When $H(p)$ is *semi* definite, the the quadratic term can be zero in some points and all depends of the "garbage". In your case, the quadratic term is $−zw$ that is dominant except when $zw=0$, but takes positive **and** negative values and $(0,0,0,0)$ is a saddle point.

Comment: Sorry but i still don't understand. it's too complicated. my class doesn't do taylor expansion?

Comment: and can you move your comments into your answer, thanks?