# If first 1 by 1 upper left submatrix (principal minor) = 0, conclude straightaway saddle point ? - Question 8

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, determinant

Find all local extremal points for the function $f(x,y) = x^3 - 3xy+y^3 $ and classify
their type.

For $H(f)(0,0),$ I see that $D_1 = \det [0] = 0$. So according to [the criteria that I already posted here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/804464/87058), because 0 is neither + nor -, can't we conclude immediately that $(0,0)$ must be a critical point? Why does the solution calculate $D_2$?

I forgot to define $D_j$. It's just the upper left j x j submatrix, the principal minor.

> [image]

Comment: To say that it is a critical point you only need to have $f_x=f_y=0.$ But to classify what kind of critical it is  $D_1=0$ is not enough. You need also $D_2.$

Comment: Care to define $D_1$ and $D_2$?

Comment: This is not crucial to the question you ask but note that the $(2,2)$ entry of $H(f)$ should read $6y$, not $9y$, hence the $(2,2)$ entry of $H(f)(1,1)$ should read $6$ and $D_2=27$, not $45$, which does not change the conclusion that $(1,1)$ is a local minimum.

Comment: If the sign of $D_2$ is positive, this means that the point is an extremum, but it is not enough to know if this is a minimum or a maximum. to know it, you should check the ign of the trace: if this is positive, then it is a minimum, if it is negative, this is a maximum. If the sign of $D_2$ is negative, then it is a saddle point. If $D_2=0$, you need a further analysis as for instance with $f(x,y)=x^4+y^4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In dimension $2$, if the Hessian matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}0&b\\b&d\end{pmatrix}$ with $b\ne0$ then the eigenvalues are $\frac12(d\pm\sqrt{d^2+4b^2})$, one positive and one negative, hence the critical point is a saddle point. If the Hessian matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&d\end{pmatrix}$, the eigenvalues are $0$ and $d$ hence the critical point is not a saddle point.

To sum up, the fact that the $(1,1)$ entry of the Hessian matrix at a critical point is $0$ is *almost*, but *not quite*, sufficient to declare that this point is a saddle point.